# MAMP and CodeIgniter - Simple form post returns Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Bashing my head on the wall to resolve this error. I'm using codeigniter 2 with MAMP on localhost.  This site works perfectly on WAMP (Windows 10) and all configuration is the same.

I have a simple login form which, on submission does not even hit my post method but displays the error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/src/system/core/CodeIgniter.php:237`

I've experimented with test var_dumps in my dologin function. Interestingly the error goes away and the output from the var_dump displays if I add https://localhost/mysite/src/session/dologin directly in my address bar.

**Core/CodeIgniter.php lines 235 - 238**

```
function &get_instance()
{
    return CI_Controller::get_instance();
}
```

**Login Form**

```
<form action="https://localhost/mysite/src/session/dologin" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />

    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />

    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

**CI Login Function (Loading Login View)**

```
public function login()
{
    $this->output->enable_profiler(false);

    $this->data['system_message'] = null;
    if (file_exists(SYSTEM_MESSAGE)) {
        $this->data['system_message'] = file_get_contents(SYSTEM_MESSAGE);
    }

    $this->template->write_view('content', 'session/login', $this->data);
    $this->template->render();
}
```

**CI Login Form Post Function**

```
public function dologin()
{
    global $pre_filter;

    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = base64_encode($pre_filter['password']);
    $auth = $this->rest->post('authentication/sessions', ['username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'endpoint' => $this->sitecode]);
    //...further processing
}
```

Both CI controller functions are within this class which extends a custom controller.

```
class Session extends MySite_Controller {
}
```

**NOTE:**
BASEPATH is correct (checked via several debug var_dumps)
$config[‘base_url’] = '', is set to be blank
.htaccess is set correctly and Apache’s Rewrite module is turned on
$config[‘log_threshold’] = 0, logs switched off

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this works

Within system/core/CodeIgniter.php, on around line 75, change:

```
set_error_handler('_exception_handler');
```

to...

```
set_exception_handler('_exception_handler');
```